# Limiting a 24VDC fan's draw to 1ampere

Tags: current, dc, fan

I have a 24 VDC fan that is rated for 3 A draw at maximum speed. I want to limit it to only using 1 A at 24 VDC.

The device I'm building uses a 5 A 24 VDC power supply (already bought them) and I only have 1 ampere available for this fan (4 A in use elsewhere.)

Is it possible to limit the amount of power going to this fan to 1 A? (I understand that this will significantly reduce the speed of the fan.)

V = I x R

I have a hunch that this is a situation where I just don't fully understand current. Volts is pressure and amperes is the flow through the system.

Comment: please add the fan specs to your post

Comment: Get a slower/less powerful fan?

Comment: It might seem counter-intuitive, but you might be able to reduce the current (and power) drawn by the fan by restricting its airflow. You can see an example of this phenomenon when you block the suction of a vacuum cleaner, and the motor will speed up.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet would be something like this between your supply and fan. Be aware that motor torque and speed will be affected. The regulator will also dissipate a significant amount of power/heat so you will need to cool it. However: Depending on the specs of the fan the current specified could be inrush or stall current. These are usually significantly higher than operating current so depending on how hard you are loading it, you maybe could just attach it directly.

[image]

Image from: https://www.onsemi.com/download/data-sheet/pdf/lm317-d.pdf

Comment: This assumes that the fan will operate correctly at significantly reduced input voltage, which is not always the case.

Comment: Assuming that the fan might draw just 1 A at 12 VDC, the linear regulator will dissipate 12 watts. If the fan is a resistive load, it would draw 1A at 6 VDC, and the regulator would dissipate 18 watts. A better solution would be a simple PWM controller, or a buck converter. At 50%, you could get 2 A for the fan at 12 VDC, with input of just 1 A.

Comment: Thank you !  I'll research this further

Comment: PstechPaul, I see your comment too, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can test to drive a fan with a voltage and with a current regulation, with the current regulation it will make noise!

- Better use a stepdown regulator and change the voltage till the current will be reduced to 1A. Measure the current during you change the voltage.
- The fan does have a higher current if it will start, because of this a soft-start option would be good.
  There are stepdown regulators which can do voltage and current limitation and you can set a start-input-voltage, like the [LTC3780](https://de.aliexpress.com/item/32902533475.html) what you can find on Aliexpress.
  Or this version with only current and voltage limitation: [LTC3780 - AT120](https://de.aliexpress.com/item/1005003493527477.html)